# Weird error I receive from Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to make a tkinter project but as I tried to run for like the third time it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/cool/Documents/STM Wisepay Service.py", line 63, in <module> 
  app = App(root)
File "/Users/cool/Documents/STM Wisepay Service.py", line 20, in __init__
  self.create_buttons()  
File "/Users/cool/Documents/STM Wisepay Service.py", line 30, in create_buttons
  tk.Button(button_frame, text = "Add to Debt", commmand = self.debt).grid(column = 6, row = 5)  
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2366, in __init__
  Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw  
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2296, in __init__
  (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf)
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-commmand"
```

What can I do to fix this? What are the problems with my code?

Here is my code:
https://pastebin.com/mWPEFbpz

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Take the time to create a [mcve] and include it directly in the question.

Comment: Your code does not seem to define what `self.debt` is...

Comment: read the error message very carefully. Read every character.

Comment: Please copy and paste a traceback without the editing that adds blank lines and removes the indent of code lines.  After pasting, select the whole block and click the {} symbol to indent it as code.

Comment: In function calls, do not add spaces around '='.  For instance, `text="Add to Debt"`.

Comment: `commmand` does not have 3 m's

Comment: @TerryJanReedy this has no affect on the code at all. It is simple a style preference. I know PEP8 style guidelines show to not use space there but it does not hurt.

Answer (score 2):

**You are spelling command wrong** (three m's)

You are passing it a variable called `commmand` and it doesn't know how to use that variable.

```
tk.Button(... commmand = ...
```

You can see it in the error message right here

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-commmand"
```

These python error messages are actually very helpful. I would encourage you to read them carefully to catch stuff like this.